# Как в Freemarker работать с xml с названиями узлов с двоеточиями?

Tags: java, freemarker

Freemarker. Как работать с xml с названиями узлов с двоеточиями?

xml:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <Name>Test</Name>
</S:Envelope>
```

поле в модели:

```
«${doc["item["S:Envelope"]/ Name"]}»
```

Ошибка:

```
fr.opensagres.xdocreport.core.XDocReportException: freemarker.core.NonStringOrTemplateOutputException: For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), or "template output" , but this has evaluated to a sequence+hash (wrapper: f.e.dom.NodeListModel):
==> doc.item["S:Envelope"].item["xmlns:S"]  [in template "fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx.DocxReport@3fa77460!word/document.xml" at line 4, column 1487]

----
Tip: This XML query result can't be used as string because for that it had to contain exactly 1 XML node, but it contains 0 nodes. That is, the constructing XML query has found no matches.
----

----
FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
    - Failed at: ${doc.item["S:Envelope"].item["xmlns:...  [in template "fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx.DocxReport@3fa77460!word/document.xml" at line 4, column 1485]
----
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.freemarker.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.process(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:167)
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.freemarker.FreemarkerTemplateEngine.processWithCache(FreemarkerTemplateEngine.java:112)
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.AbstractTemplateEngine.process(AbstractTemplateEngine.java:112)
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.template.AbstractTemplateEngine.process(AbstractTemplateEngine.java:83)
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.AbstractXDocReport.processTemplateEngine(AbstractXDocReport.java:775)
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.AbstractXDocReport.process(AbstractXDocReport.java:521)
    at fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.AbstractXDocReport.process(AbstractXDocReport.java:487)
    at Main.main(Main.java:32)
Caused by: freemarker.core.NonStringOrTemplateOutputException: For "${...}" content: Expected a string or something automatically convertible to string (number, date or boolean), or "template output" , but this has evaluated to a sequence+hash (wrapper: f.e.dom.NodeListModel):
==> doc.item["S:Envelope"].item["xmlns:S"]  [in template "fr.opensagres.xdocreport.document.docx.DocxReport@3fa77460!word/document.xml" at line 4, column 1487]

----
Tip: This XML query result can't be used as string because for that it had to contain exactly 1 XML node, but it contains 0 nodes. That is, the constructing XML query has found no matches.
----
```

Comment: Узлы с двоеточиями содержат префикс пространства имён. [XML namespaces](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/xgui_declarative_details.html#autoid_145)

Comment: не помогло 
<#ftl ns_prefixes={"S":"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"}>

Comment: «${doc["item["Envelope"]/Name"]}»

Comment: Вы определили префикс в первой строке, но не используете его во второй.

Comment: К тому же узел Name тоже может иметь неймспейс по умолчанию (дефолтный), без префикса. Есть ли таковой, я не могу сказать, - нужно видеть весь xml.

Comment: я привёл весь xml

Comment: Значит у Name нет пространства имен.

Comment: `http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/` != `schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope`

Comment: попробовал изменить xml на <S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" >
   <S:Name>Test</S:Name>
</S:Envelope> не помогло

Comment: модель выглядела так: «${doc["item["S:Envelop"]/item["S:Name"]"]}

Comment: >> http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/ != schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope - http исчезает при отображении

Comment: Чтобы вставлять код (одну строку) в комментарии, используйте символ backtick ` как кавычки (находится в левом верхнем углу клавиатуры; и да, почитайте справку SO).

Comment: Я не знаю freemarker. Однако, что такое `doc` и `item` в вашем коде?

Comment: item - из синтаксиса freemarker, doc - из внешней подсистемы